# Display transparent text from Java program

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to create a Java application that displays text on the screen, in such a way that it is not contained in any form or canvas, at least not any visible one, but rather just display it on top of the thing that is currently displaying on the computer.

I'd prefer to use it in pure Java, but I guess if there is some third party library or compiled C API's then that's fine too.

If possible then I'd also like something like Ubuntu's Always on top feature, so that if I click some other window the text still is displayed on top of it.

Is there any way to make JFrames transparent?

This is kind of what I'm aiming for, only doing it in Java
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QkxT8pC17nw/T1n_rlr20aI/AAAAAAAAAj0/xbJjYObc4Bw/s1600/screenCaptureRainmeter.png

Comment: See the Java example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: OP: Transparent text would not be visible. I figure you must mean translucent (partially transparent). What feature does this intended functionality provide for the end user? @SergiyMedvynskyy: Note that anything short of transparent and it will intercept mouse events that the user intends for the 'beneath' app.

Comment: yes. Translucent text or transparent background would be right. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Tip: Add @SergiyMedvynskyy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. In that comment, you seem to be replying to me, yet have not answered the question I asked. What is the answer to the question? **What feature does this intended functionality provide for the end user?**

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson
The feature would of course be a widget-like application that displays text on top of whatever the user is doing right now, without the visual overhead of having a complete window taking up screen size. Possible use cases: alarm clock, rss reader, system monitoring etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you problem basically boils down to making the window transparent.  To that end you should start by looking at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

The next thing to keep in mind is the fact that most Swing component's are opaque by default, so just beware of that

[image: On top]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("I'm on top");
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 64));
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(label);
        }

    }

}
```

You may also want to have a look at [`Window#setAlwaysOnTop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-)